# Why is my bathroom sink leaking around the overflow seal?

Tags: plumbing, leak, bathroom-fixtures

Can anyone tell me why I have water leaking out from under the actual sink? It’s coming from the overflow “Reservoir” area? The sink is draining completely fine otherwise. Just replaced the sink drain.

[image]

Comment: Seems like your work on the drain may have tweaked the old overflow trough adhesive and cracked it loose. Is that a possibility?

Comment: I don’t think I did, but possibly. Lol. That’s what I get for messing around with something I have no clue about!! I wonder if I could use silicone caulk to try and fix it?

Comment: I don't think I'd try to repair that seal from the outside. I'd look at pulling that channel off, cleaning away the old adhesive, and re-bonding it. I'd use something stronger than silicone. Urethane might work.

Comment: I take that back. It's maybe worth smearing a layer of 100% silicone over the joint. Couldn't really hurt. Give it a good day to cure.

Comment: Ok!!! I’ll give the silicone a try and see how it goes! At this point I’m willing to try anything!! Thank you for your help!! 

Comment: I would agree with  @Isherwood, try and seal first with a layer of calking if that wont hold pull it down and clean and reseal. As long as the inside finish or porcelain is in good shape a minor repair may last your lifetime. There is very little pressure there lass than 1/2 a pound and probably less than that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sfors on trying to seal up the leak areas, as this will make plunging a future clog in the primary drain possible.

Although, the rust and leaks being that high up tells me your overflow's outlet into the primary drain is blocked and the overflow is staying mostly full, instead of freely draining straight through.

The overflow's outlet is a side port hole just below the primary drain's opening, so you may have access to it to confirm it's a real drain (there was a very stupid period when they were just for expected appearance) and is cleared when fished from the overflow inlet above.

Now, if you don't see a side port inside the primary drain, then the wrong drain was put into the sink with the overflow being totally deleted as a drain and does indeed just fill up...until it finally turned itself back into a drain, the wrong way.

Comment: Good point about it not draining well, I had one similar and it was exactly that (didn't drain quickly so water would get backed up)...definitely worth addressing that as well...

Comment: Thank you. Too many times I've seen drain putty oozed right into the overflow port.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just fixed a sink that had the same problem so I had to peel that whole thing off and then I took contact cement and put it on both pieces let them dry added a little bit more let it dry and then I stick it back together after that I placed silicone all the way around it too so they keep it sealed and it’s work just fine it was a pain in the butt with the contact cement but you’ve got to get it on there just right the first time so be very careful press it on and hold it for about 30 seconds and you should be good to go let everything dry Thoroughly for at least a day if not two and you shouldn’t have anymore problems! Let me know how it works for you I would appreciate it thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you'll take a couple of minutes to [take the tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the help center, you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not your run-of-the-internet discussion forum. As it stands, you've asked a **Question** by posting it in the box marked **Answer**. Now there's nowhere for someone to answer your question. Please feel free to [ask a whole new question](//diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) - nobody will think poorly of you for doing so.

Comment: Actually, @DanielGriscom, the only question was a request to "let me know how this solution works for you". That, honestly, isn't how things work here either, but he didn't ask a whole new question here, he actually provided an answer describing how he fixed the problem when he had it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the integrity of the sink bowl has been compromised. Looks like it's time for a new sink! Is it cast iron? Seems to be rusted through, especially on the left side of the pic. You could try repairing it with some spray on rubber sealant like [FlexSeal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ECGTK4K) or something similar

Comment: I don't think it's rusted through. There's barely any rust showing, if that's rust at all.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is cast Iron. The inside of the sink looks just fine though. No rust at all. You think i could try silicon caulk around it to seal it? Im a military wife trying to fix this mess on my own and I’m pretty clueless....lol

Comment: Silicon caulk might work and it's probably cheaper than something like FlexSeal but I've seen amazing things (on TV) with the latter that might make a more permanent seal/repair. Worst case scenario, you could always try repairing with silicon caulk then if it doesn't work, just remove it. Another option is to talk to some guys about products they sell to seal water at a place like Ace Hardware, Lowes, Home Depot, etc. It really looks like the center membrane seal is no longer good - but if you seal it, seal from front to back - the whole thing - so the water doesn't just go somewhere else.

Comment: Oh, and if there's rust, since it's cast iron, if you don't use something like rust converter, the life of that sink is even more compromised. Basically, sealing it is applying a band-aid to the whole thing and it's ticking time bomb that will just leak on down the road because the rust will get worse.

Comment: The cool thing about cast is it takes decades to rust out. Ever heard of cast drain lines? Raw cast inside and out . I have owned homes with cast drain lines that were still in good shape and over 100 years old. My current house they are only 90 years old.

Answer (score 0):

I ran jb-weld (the quick variety, probably doesn't affect it) all up and down that bad seam, seems to be holding well.

Other tip: try and clean it out as best you can before caulking/jb-weld.

Other tip: try to figure out if the drain is backed up, and clear it, normally water shouldn't be getting into that seam at all...

FlexSeal on top wouldn't hurt but shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: "I ran..." Are you Absmith1112 now posting under a different account? If so, you should request that they get merged. If not, please clarify that statement as it's rather confusing.

Comment: Nope.  I ran jb weld up and down and into the seam from top to bottom :)